# Get pipe operator from name space

Tags: r, namespaces

I cannot understand why the following code failed.

```
`%>%`  <- utils::getFromNamespace("%>%", "stringr")
```

> Error in get(x, envir = ns, inherits = FALSE) : 
>       object '%>%' not found

From the above code, I think I can use pipe operator `%>%` without attaching its library `stringr`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stringr` doesn't define `%>%`, it just imports it from `magrittr`. Have a look [at the `stringr` NAMESPACE file](https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr/blob/master/NAMESPACE#L53) for reference. You can use `magrittr` and it will work:

```
`%>%` <- getFromNamespace("%>%", "magrittr")
```

Comment: I can understand, thank you.  Executing the code `help( `%>%` )` , it launches four package,  stringr , 
  dplyr,   purrr,  magrittr . So, I misunderstand. Thank you.